# Java Pattern (numbers)

Tags: java

How to print the following pattern:

```
1
2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15
```

I have tried this:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Program89 here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Program91
{
   public static void main()
   {
       int z=1;
       for(int x=1;x<=5;x++)
       {
           for(int y=1;y<=z;y++)
           {
               System.out.print(z);
               z++;
           }
            System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

I tried but i got a never ending loop... Plz help...

EDIT:

I got it, I should have replaced z in for(int y=1;y<=z;y++) with x...

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error? Between 1 and y a semicolon is missing: `for(int y=1y<=z;y++)`

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock oh yea... that too....

Comment: You are incrementing both Z and Y at same time. so obviously the loop will run indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

This line has the inner loop "chasing its own tail", because `z` gets incremented in the body:

```
for(int y=1 ; y<=z ; y++) {
    ...
    z++; // <<== Here
}
```

Since both `y` and `z` increase by `1` on each iteration, `y` never catches up to `z`.

You should be comparing `y` to `x`, not to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Program89 here.
 * 
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Program91 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(k++ + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```